# PHP swagger annotation for multiple responses with the same code

Tags: php, swagger, openapi

In one of my controller methods I try to put such annotations:

```
 *     @OA\Response(
 *         response="404",
 *         description="Invalid field"
 *     ),
 *     @OA\Response(
 *         response="404",
 *         description="Entity not found"
 *     )
```

But now I get an error message from openapi, when I try to build documentation:

```
Warning: Multiple @OA\Response() with the same response="400":
```

I know that now there is a `oneOf` in swagger, which seems to be exactly for my purpose. However, I do not know how to use it.

Comment: No, it does not. I need to know, how it should look like in the form of annotations

Comment: I have a POST request, that may result in different responses and I do not know the right way to use annotations in this case.

Comment: The error makes sense, because you cannot have different response body definitions for the same error code., you will need to set 400 for invalid field and 404 for entity not found.

Answer (score 5):

The code below solves that issue, hope it helps

```
     *      @OA\Response(
     *          response="404",
     *          description="Errors",
     *          @OA\JsonContent(
     *              @OA\Schema(type="string"),
     *              @OA\Examples(
     *                  example="string",
     *                  value="Account not exist",
     *                  summary="Account not exist."
     *              ),
     *              @OA\Examples(
     *                  example="string2",
     *                  value="User does not exist",
     *                  summary="User does not exist"
     *              ),
     *          )
     *      ),
```

[image: screenshot of Swagger]

Comment: Works beautifully!

Answer (score 2):

```
     *@OA\Response(
     *          response=200,
     *          description="Successful operation",
     *          @OA\JsonContent(
     *              oneOf={
     *              @OA\Schema(ref="#/components/responses/schema1"),
     *              @OA\Schema(ref="#/components/responses/schema2"),
     *     }
     *          ),
     *),
```